# Unable to delete folder with shutil.rmtree() with ArcPy?

Tags: python, arcpy

Unable to delete folder with `shutil.rmtree()` with arcpy:

```py
del mxd
delete_path_edit = temp_dir_extended
delete_path_forward = '/'.join(delete_path_edit.split('\\'))
shutil.rmtree(delete_path_forward)
```

#### ERROR

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PythonScripts\exportToPDFFolderV1.py", line 166, in <module>
    shutil.rmtree(delete_path_forward)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\shutil.py", line 252, in rmtree
    onerror(os.remove, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\shutil.py", line 250, in rmtree
    os.remove(fullname)
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: u'D:/MaharashtraIDSI/TempFolder/temp_custom\\Clip_IDSI_SA_2006_001_masked.img'

Failed to execute (ExportToPDFFolder).
```

Comment: That's an OS error, not really anything to do with GIS.

Comment: I second what Vince says as an OS error. However, with that being said, it looks like you have schema locks in your script as indicated by your error message where it says `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process` is the key to the problem.  Be sure to clean up your locks and `shutil.rmtree()` should work.  If not, you could also try `arcpy.management.Delete()`

Comment: This isn't a *lock* so much as an actively used file.  The process responsible for having the file open may not be the same as the application running ArcPy (in which case it can't be affected by Python, short of killing the process).

Comment: Looks like you're doing `arcpy.mapping` calls. Best advice here is to `del` every single variable you create, and then try to `os.remove` or as crmackey points out, `arcpy....Delete'.  I have seen instances where something holds on to a reference in these workflows, but could never figure it out completely to get a bug logged

Comment: @crmackey I have tried using arcpy.Delete_management() for deleting the data but it does not work inside the code. Once I run arcpy.Delete_management() on ArcMap10.3  shell promt then the folder is deleted. Why so, why doesn't it work from the script ?

Comment: @KHibma yes I have deleted all the variables still it is not able to delete the empty folder

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I could solve it this way:

```
folder = r'path\to\your\folder'
os.chmod(folder, stat.S_IWRITE) #You have to import stat module of course
os.remove(folder)
```

It seems that there is a process still running or in memory when you are trying to delete the folder.

Comment: Error : `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PythonScripts\exportToPDFFolderV1.py", line 171, in <module>
    os.remove(folder)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: u'D:/MaharashtraIDSI/TempFolder/temp_custom'

Failed to execute (ExportToPDFFolder).`

Comment: I will also like to add the folder that I am trying to delete is empty